# Help finding specific book

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm studying Engineering and I'm in my second year, studying Multivariable Calculus, but my University is kind of hard teaching me fresh calculus with topology and analysis, and is kind of hard, so I would like to find a good book, a recent one if possible with Multivariable calculus seen from the perspective of a fresh student but with enough advancement to approach the subject with analysis and topology. Any suggestion?

PS: The problem I find with multivariable analysis is that I don't understand the "importance" or "where am I going with this?" with all those theorems and proofs....is like...is a constant bombarding of theorems and proofs, but without telling me where am I going, or how I use them, or show me a broader perspective of the theory so I can look at it simpler...

Comment: which book your univ recommends?

Comment: I like Folland's book [Advanced Calculus](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Calculus-Gerald-B-Folland/dp/0130652652).

Comment: I would recommend video lectures on [MIT OpenCourseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) and on youtube and after a while you can start reading books that others have recommended. Watching video lectures on math has made a real difference on my mind.

Comment: mm apostol, fleming, c. buck, H.cartan, but they seems quite complicate....i find hard to memorize so many theorems and proofs, instead of really understanding, THE USE of them, the meaning of them, their importance, their implication, application, instead of just....proofs....

Comment: You may want to look at [**Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471198269) by Mary P. Boas, and [**Div, Grad, Curl, and All That: An Informal Text on Vector Calculus**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0393925161) by H. M. Schey, and [**Schaum's Outline of Advanced Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0393925161) by Murray R. Spiegel.

Comment: I see that someone else has already recommended the book by Mary P. Boas. Here's another book that might be useful, because of its expository merits of topology and advanced multivariable calculus in the first half of the book: [**Differential Topology with a View to Applications**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/027300283X) by David R. J. Chillingworth. The prices listed at amazon.com are amazingly high, but maybe that is a reflection of the merits of the book (no one is willing to part with it cheaply). I don't think I paid more than about $30 for my copy, but that was back in 1978.

Comment: Regarding Chillingworth's book, I posted an excerpt from it in this [30 April 2011 ap-calculus post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7443285) (archived at Math Forum) that will give you an idea of what I mean by "expository merits". The book is extremely good at describing the "big picture" of things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Kolk's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521551145), if not, this might help you.

Comment: mmm, I will check it, thanks.

Comment: This seems pretty stiff for a 2nd year engineering student. I can imagine such a student being ready for sheaf cohomology and spectral sequences in a couple of years if he/she decides to pursue graduate study in engineering.

Answer (score 1):

These lectures are on multivariable calculus . i studied from these lectures only(Got good marks) and they are perfect .By prof Adrian Banner from Princeton University

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDByROsGzuk

Also book they use is Thomas Finney Calculus

Hope that helps !

Comment: yes but thomas is too easy, it doesnt aproach calculus through analysis neither topology

Comment: @Matias Firstly i think thomas is good and certainly not very hard but i also think that doing real analysis without having prior knowledge of calculus 1,2,3 will be difficult and virtually impossible .Also Spivak's calculus is good one and can be used with K.Ross Elementary analysis for that purpose